# How do I set a floating element automatically fill the remaining height of its parent element (height not fixed and displayed as a table)?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-float

I have the following code:

```css
.parent {width: 960px; display: table}

.1 {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  height: 1000px; /* it can be smaller or bigger than this value to fit its content */
}

.2 {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 20px;
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
}

.3 {
  width: 45%;
  margin: 20px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="1">1</div>
  <div class="2">2</div>
  <div class="3">3</div>
</div>
```

How do I write the CSS for class "3" so that its height automatically fill the remaining height of the table (in the case above, 720px, as the parent element will have, I assume, height of 1000px too)? Note that the height of class "1" can change according to its contents.

Off-topic: Is there a better way to make it look like the picture below other than the codes I'm using now (only using CSS and HTML)?

[The Image of the Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJaYb.png)

Comment: You have to make a choice. float or display. according to your image, `display:grid;` would be the best and easier to use. example : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/WJWyJr

Comment: Is it possible to use float instead? Unfortunately, I've not been taught neither how to use display:grid nor any of the properties you've included in your example. If it's not possible, I will try to look them all up. @G-Cyr

Comment: float is not meant to draw columns of same height. display: table, flex and grid could help you. I believe here only grid will be efficient :(

Comment: ... codepen on line again ... https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BxEPdp

Comment: @G-Cyr Hi, I've just read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout. I understand what your codes mean now, but I do have problems from line 33. I tried deleting them and the numbers disappeared. In which section can I read about those properties (grid, table, css or something else)? Also, if there is a rule of thumb, when should I use float, display:table, flex or grid?

Comment: About counter, you can read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters . for the use of float or displays the choice is to be made for the result you expect .float will slide elements side by side to left or right as long as there is room, then they go down. table shrinks on content and will make rows that will not break, flex can let rows break, grid allows to draw a grid where element can span rows and columns ... they all have different purpose. Look at tutorials and play around with them to get familiar with. Choice is then easier ;)

Comment: **note** also that a class name should not start with a number or special characters, firefox nor chrome here for instance will not accept it and style will not be applied (an old css rule) but think about more like a good practice to start your classname with a regular letter ;)  see your code with numbers and letters  https://jsfiddle.net/fjg8qbgc/

Comment: @G-Cyr I see, okay thanks for all the tips and answers! Have a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. the third element(green) will adjust based on the height of `.one`. But it is implemented based on the assumption that `.two` is having fixed dimensions.

```css
.parent {
    width: 960px;
    border: solid 2px #999;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.one {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}
.two {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    height: 200px;
    background: #aaa;
}
.three {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class='one'>one</div>
    <div class='two'>two</div>
    <div class='three'>three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've never used "position", so I read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position. 
From what I've read, position:relative on parent element is necessary so that .three knows where to compute its "left" and "top", right (in this case, "parent")? Also, why is it necessary to use the "float:left" on "parent"? I tried without the float and it broke. Off-topic: On the link I sent specifically in "Sticky positioning" section, why does "A" disappear even though it's a sticky? Is it because "B" replaces "A" or is it because it's already out of "A" 's div?


@Pons

Comment: 1.If you do not apply relative position for the parent element, The absolute element(.three) will be positioned relative to body. So left:50% will be calculated based on your browser window. Similarly the other offsets also.

2. Since the child elements are floated elements, if you don't apply float for the parent, the parent will not stretch along with the size of child elements. If this happens, in our case "bottom:0" will be broken for .three. If you want to avoid float, you may apply "over flow:hidden" for the parent. But beware it will hide the overflows if something is there.

Comment: Thank you for the answers! Should I accept your answer if I'm still waiting for a comment response from another user? @Pons

Comment: Welcome! Its all up to you. Cheers!